# Can't send push notification via API Trigger

Tags: mobilepush

I created an API Triggered push notification on the MobilePush dashboard, but when I try to trigger/send it, the API returns a 500 error.

I'm using Postman do send the following request:

POST: `http://www.exacttargetapis.com/push/v1/messageContact/{{message_id}}/send`

Body:

```
{
  "deviceTokens": [
    "948966EF5*******************************************************"
  ]
}
```

Headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer {{api_access_token}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Response:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "errorcode": 0,
    "documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to get the 500 to happen so my guess is something is being formatted oddly in the final call. Can you paste what the final call looks like once the variables are inserted?

Here is a sample of mine:

```
POST /push/v1/messageContact/NTk1MzoxMTQ***/send HTTP/1.1
Host: www.exacttargetapis.com
Authorization: Bearer 1*************l
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3753b5f7-****-****-****-***********

{
    "deviceTokens": [
        "c8jpkj_JkzQ***************"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/kWhkLER4

Comment: Darn... I made my request identical and it is still working for me. I sent you a linked-in message if you want to keep chatting about this and I can do a quick look around.